# Change default colors in ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, default, color-blindness

I use the following code to generate the following plot:

```
ggplot(CellSite_means, aes(x=CellSite, y=MYCA, fill=Cell)) + geom_col() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[My original plot with default colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gZDx.jpg)

But the default blue color scheme is way too subtle. Instead I want a wider variety of colors for each cell (cells are numbered and there is an A and B site within each). Preferably I would like to use the colorblind palette.  Even better, I would want the color-blind palette to be my default for all ggplots.
I tried using the following

```
cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
ggplot(CellSite_means, aes(x=CellSite, y=MYCA, fill=Cell)) + geom_col() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)) + scale_fill_manual(name="Cell",values=setnames(cbPalette, 1:6)) and a bunch of other iterations and palettes, but can't make it change.
```

This must be really simple, please help.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default colour scale for ggplot2 in the global options. Example below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

default_colour <- function(...) {
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = cbPalette,
    ...
  )
}

options("ggplot2.discrete.colour" = default_colour)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

The same thing also works for `"ggplot2.discrete.fill"`, `"ggplot2.continuous.colour"` and `"ggplot2.continuous.fill"`.